# RestAPI's deleting a model with another model

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, mongoose-schema

EDIT:  I've just been informed by my professor not to access the driver from within the admin. Should be inside driver only.

I'm working on a project using restAPI's and a requirement is that an admin can delete driver.

They each both have their own schema and model in their own .js file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var AdminSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String
});
mongoose.model('Admin', AdminSchema); // Model name is 'Admin'
module.exports = mongoose.model('Admin'); // Export for use in other parts of program
```

Similarly for the driver...

I'm using Postman to test all of this,

Now i'm stuck trying to have my admin be able to delete from both the admin database and the driver database using their ID's

the DELETE method for the admin looks like:

```
var Admin = require('./Admin');
var Driver = require('./Driver'); 
.
.
.
router.delete('/:id', function (req, res) {
    Admin.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function (err, admin) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem deleting the admin.");
        res.status(200).send("Admin: " + admin.name + " was deleted.");
    });
});
```

I've tried many things, including the method looking like this

```
router.delete('/:id', function (req, res) {
    Admin.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function (err, admin) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem deleting the admin.");
        res.status(200).send("Admin: " + admin.name + " was deleted.");
    });
    Driver.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function (err, driver) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem deleting the driver.");
        res.status(200).send("Driver: " + driver.name + " was deleted.");
    });
});
```

But this doesn't work, and I've tried having the methods separately, but the program only looks for whichever one is first, so if I have the method to delete the driver before the admin's delete method, it will find drivers, but not admins. It simply triggers the driver's error message and doesn't trigger the admins delete method.

Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. This is my first time learning about this stuff, and it's very interesting, but it's quite tricky!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way you call the DB queries is incorrect. Both calls `Admin.findByIdAndRemove` and `Driver.findByIdAndRemove` are asynchronous so you need to treat them as such. You also **can't call** `res.status(200).send(..` **twice** from the route handler. It should cause an error *"Can't send headers after they were already sent"* or something like that.

One way could be:

```
router.delete('/:id', function (req, res) {
    var response = '';
    Driver.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function (err, driver) {

        if (err) 
            response += "There was a problem deleting the driver.";
        else
            response += "Driver: " + driver.name + " was deleted.";

        Admin.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function (err, admin) {

            if (err) 
                response += "There was a problem deleting the admin.";
            else
                response += ("Admin: " + admin.name + " was deleted.";

            // you can't use error status since both db results could be different

            res.status(200).send(response);
        });

    });
});
```

Also note that making multiple queries makes it difficult to use corect http status since each db query could have diferent result

Better way would be to have 2 routes one for admin and the other for driver

```
router.delete('/driver/:id', function (req, res) {
    Driver.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function (err, driver) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem deleting the driver.");
        res.status(200).send("Driver: " + driver.name + " was deleted.");
    });
});

router.delete('/admin/:id', function (req, res) {
    Admin.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function (err, admin) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem deleting the admin.");
        res.status(200).send("Admin: " + admin.name + " was deleted.");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Molda 

I edited this at the top, but it seems that my professor said we shouldn't use the Driver model inside the Admin